# Multi-agent reinforcement learning: An introduction

Tags: simulation, reinforcement-learning, game-theory

I would like to make a Tic-Tac-Toe game with 10X10 board and I want to have 2 agents playing against each other and learning to play from interaction.

A naive approach could be taken - to simply let agents learn as if the other agent were stationary and thus part of the envidonment. However, I think this would work only if actions of the agents would not have significant influence  on the environment of either of them.

Please correct me if the following statement is not true:
Single agent RL may not be applied in case of a game, where one agent is a part of the environment of the other and the other way around, since the transitions in MDP would not be stationary (one agents' strategy influences other agents' strategy and vice versa and as both of them are changing strategy according to their foe, the environment transitions change), which would violate the convergence properties of RL algorithms. An option would be for both agents to account for the other agents' learning.

I read [An Analysis of Stochastic Game Theory for Multiagent
Reinforcement Learning](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~mmv/papers/00TR-mike.pdf) paper and the multi-agent RL seems to be a promissing framework and quite a lot of research has been done in this area. However, I am struggling to find a comprehensive overview of MARL methods.

Is there any self-contained introduction to multi-agent reinforcement learning? Something like [Sutton & Barto](http://people.inf.elte.hu/lorincz/Files/RL_2006/SuttonBook.pdf)? If not, what are some easy-to-understand resources to start with, given that I somehow understand RL concepts in a single-agent setting?

An overview of research on MARL can be found [here](https://github.com/LantaoYu/MARL-Papers).

Comment: @NeilSlater Thanks for your response as always :) I tried to put the question in a better context and added some useful resources. It seems like I will have to run through the research articles anyways. Will update the question with new discoveries or maybe write some comprehensive summary myself.

Comment: I still don't know the answer, but it is getting close to stuff I do know. Your example is for a two player zero-sum game (one player's win is the other's loss). This is simpler and better studied than generic multi-agent RL scenarios. If you specifically limit your question to 2-player zero-sum or classic games where the reward is the eventual win/loss, then I think there is quite a lot of material available. Including some details in Sutton & Barto second edition.

Comment: The basic "trick" for a zero-sum game is that you only need learn one value function because player B's value function is the negative of player A's value function. So you can use RL models very similar to the single agent's view.

Comment: Thanks, I will surely check the second edition of Sutton & Barto. Should the result of learning in our case result in Nash equilibrium policies? And once the agents learn the NE policy, would they be able to never lose against an arbitrary (say human) oponent, given that there would be no more exploration?

Comment: Those are more complex questions. I'm not sure of the relationship to Nash equilibrium. Only relatively simple games can be fully solved with this kind of learner - but yes if fully solved then depending on game the agent should be able to force the best possible result. Some games when played perfectly by both sides might give advantage to first or second player, so no the agent is not guaranteed to avoid losing, it depends on the details of the game. 3x3 tic-tac-toe of course allows both players to force a draw, and an RL agent should find that.